# At the instant of release of an object from rest. Is the only force that can act its weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Q3 from a mechanics exam past paper:[image]

I can do parts i) and ii) but for iii) in finding the angular acceleration, i used $C=I\alpha$, where $C$ is the applied couple or torque, $I$ is the moment of inertia for the lamina about A and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration.

At the instant the object is released the only force acting on it is its own weight. Hence, $6g*0.8=9\alpha$ which yields $\alpha=5.227$.

However the mark-scheme says the answer is $\alpha=1.65$, as they have taken into account the frictional couple. Here is the mark-scheme:[image]

**It was my understanding that at the moment of release no friction *(and hence no frictional couple)* can act as there is no movement (yet).**

So could someone please kindly explain what the mark-scheme is talking about?

Comment: Actually there is movement because _AB_ goes from horizontal initially to vertical when $\omega = 2.4$

Comment: [Link to same question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/910043/101979)

Comment: This question should not close as the OP has some confusion on how to apply the equations of motion.

Comment: See [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80449/392) on how to apply the equations of motion on a point away from the center of mass.

Comment: @ja72 I have checked your link carefully. But are you saying the mark-scheme you see above is correct or incorrect? As they have applied equations of motion at the point $A$ and **NOT** $G$ ($A$ is away from the COM).

Comment: @CountTo10 I have a favour to ask of my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friction does not depend on velocity (unlike viscous drag). An object that is stationary on a table will continue to be stationary when you push it gently - because there is an opposing force of friction.

So no, your understanding is wrong: friction is present even when the object is just starting to move.

Let me draw a diagram:

[image]

That ought to clear it up...

Comment: okay thank you for your answer, i'm getting mixed views on this question as i also asked this under the stack-exchange mathematics site. Let me ask you this instead, I understand that maximum friction is reached when $F=\mu R$. So is there a frictional force acting on the object _before_ you push it gently?

Comment: If you look at the microscopic mechanism behind friction it looks a bit like a car on a road full of pot holes. When the car is standing still in the pothole, there is no force in the direction it would like to travel: but in order to get out of the pot hole, it must climb out of the hole. Similarly a truly stationary object "feels no friction" - but it cannot move until it overcomes the frictional force. The question clearly stated "a frictional couple of constant moment opposes the motion". Before you move you must overcome it.