# Newton-Euler equations in frame not centered at center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm having trouble with a step in the derivation of the Newton-Euler equations for rigid body translation and rotation when the body frame is not centered at the center of gravity.

The Newton-Euler equations in a frame $G$ attached to the center of gravity are
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
mI & 0 \\
0 & J
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{v}_G \\
\dot{\omega}_G
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
m\omega_G\times v_G \\
\omega_G\times J\omega_G
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f \\
\tau_G
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $v_G$ is the body velocity, $\omega_G$ is the body angular velocity about the center of mass, $m$ is the mass of the rigid body and $J$ is the inertia tensor, $f$ is the applied force and $\tau_G$ is an applied torque about the center of mass.

Assume now that we are interested in describing the motion with respect to some other frame $B$ such that the center of mass is at a point $\rho_G$ in this frame (the orientation of the frame $B$ being the same as that of $G$, that is, the frames are related by pure translation). Then
$$
\omega_G = \omega_B \\
v_G = v_B - \rho_G\times\omega_B \\
\tau_G = \tau_B - \rho_G\times f
$$
from which it follows that the equations become
$$
m\dot{v}_B - (m\rho_G)\times\dot{\omega}_B + m(\omega_B\times v_B + \omega_B\times\omega_B\times\rho_G) = f \\
J\dot{\omega}_B + (m\rho_G)\times\dot{v}_B + \omega_B\times J\omega_B + (m\rho_G)\times(\omega_B\times v_B + \omega_B\times\omega_B\times\rho_G - \rho_G\times\dot{\omega}_B) = \tau_B.
$$
The derivation I'm following at this point simplifies the second equation to
$$
J\dot{\omega}_B + (m\rho_G)\times\dot{v}_B + \omega_B\times J\omega_B + (m\rho_G)\times(\omega_B\times v_B) = \tau_B.
$$
I can't understand why this is allowed. Why is it true that
$$
\rho_G\times(\omega_B\times\omega_B\times\rho_G - \rho_G\times\dot{\omega}_B) = 0~?
$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivation of Newton-Euler equations of motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80433/)

Comment: Hint: Use the vector identity $a \times (b \times c) = b (a\cdot c) - c (a \cdot b)$

Comment: When you're writing triple vector products it's imperative that you use parentheses to specify the order of operations. It's not obvious to everyone which cross-product should be done first.

Comment: @BillN Yes, but due to the way the triple products appear they are all from right to left, i.e. $a\times b\times c = a\times (b\times c)$. This is why I thought relaxing the notation would not introduce any ambiguity.

Comment: @ja72 I have tried that identity and rewriting the expression in many different ways, to no avail. I'm sure this is a simple trick I'm failing to see, which is why I've asked this here so I can move on.

Comment: There is also the identity $(a \times b)\times = a \times b \times - b \times a \times$

Comment: @ja72 I think what's preventing me from getting the result is that I don't understand how the $\dot{\omega}$ term is related to $\rho_G$ and $\omega$.

Comment: Note that there is a heuristic argument here.  If $\begin{bmatrix}
mI & 0 \\0 & J\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}_G\end{bmatrix} $ is a screw and $\begin{bmatrix}f \\
\tau_G\end{bmatrix}$ is screw, then $\begin{bmatrix}
m\omega_G\times v_G \\
\omega_G\times J\omega_G
\end{bmatrix}$ must be a screw, and hence it should transform like a screw also.

Comment: @mcpca your problem shouldn't be the $\dot{\omega}$ part. The difficulty is with transforming the $\omega \times v_G$ part. See my answer now.

Comment: @mcpca - curious, are you a student or self-taught? If you want to, connect via [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jalexiou/) and ask any questions you have about rigid body mechanics, screw theory or projective geometry.

Comment: Hello, I am a student, just not of physics. I am interested in control of aerial and underwater vehicles, which is why I was interested in the equations, and also why I'm a bit out of my depth, being very new to rigid body dynamics.

Comment: @mcpca It seems you are doing the right thing. You are asking questions and deriving the equations on your own instead of taking them at face value. Good luck.

Comment: @mcpca curious- what references did you use to come up with the equations of motion at the center of mass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63704/discussion-between-mcpca-and-ja72).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using [spatial accelerations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_acceleration) for $\dot{v}_G$. So your equations of motion at the center of mass *G* are correct

$$ \pmatrix{f \\ \tau_G} = \left[ \matrix{ m & \\ & J_G} \right] \pmatrix{\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}} + \pmatrix{m \omega \times v_G \\ \omega \times J_G \omega}  $$

Notice I added a subscript on the MMOI at it is expressed about *G* and removed it from $\omega$ since it is shared by the entire rigid body.

The first parts of the equation are easily transformed to a different point *B* with 
  $$\pmatrix{f \\ \tau_B} = \left[ \matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ \rho_G \times & 1} \right] \pmatrix{f \\ \tau_G}$$
and
  $$\pmatrix{\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}} = \left[ \matrix{ 1 & -\rho_G \times \\ 0 & 1} \right] \pmatrix{\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}}$$

Your question is, how do you transform the bias forces (the last part of the equations)?

Note that $$\begin{pmatrix}m\omega\times v_{G}\\
\omega\times J_{G}\omega
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
v_{G}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m\\
 & J_{G}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_{G}\\
\omega
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the equations at *B* are

$$\begin{align}  
\pmatrix{f \\ \tau_B}  & = \underbrace{
   \left[ \matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ \rho_G \times & 1} \right]\left[ \matrix{ m & \\ & J_G} \right] 
\left[ \matrix{ 1 & -\rho_G \times \\ 0 & 1} \right] }_\mbox{6×6 spatial inertia at B}
\pmatrix{\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}} +\\ &
+ \left[ \matrix{ 1 & 0 \\ \rho_G \times & 1} \right]
\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\v_{G}\times & \omega\times\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}m\\ & J_{G}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & -\rho_{G}\times\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}v_{B}\\\omega\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align} $$

In the end you are trying to show that the last part is 
$$ 
+\begin{bmatrix}
\omega\times\\v_{B}\times & \omega\times\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\rho_{G}\times & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}m\\ & J_{G}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & -\rho_{G}\times\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}v_{B}\\\omega\end{pmatrix}$$

I can show this with

$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\v_{B}\times & \omega\times\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
\rho_{G}\times & 1
\end{bmatrix}&=\\\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
\left(v_{G}+\rho_{G}\times\omega\right)\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
\rho_{G}\times & 1
\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
\left(v_{G}+\rho_{G}\times\omega\right)+\omega\times\rho_{G}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
v_{G}\times+\left(\rho_{G}\times\omega\right)\times+\omega\times\left(\rho_{G}\times\right) & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
v_{G}\times+\left(\rho_{G}\times\omega\times-\omega\times\rho_{G}\times\right)+\omega\times\rho_{G}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}\\\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
v_{G}\times+\rho_{G}\times\omega\times+ & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
\rho_{G}\times & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\
v_{G}\times & \omega\times
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

<sub>Use the vector identity $\left(\rho_{G}\times\omega\right)\times = \rho_{G}\times\omega\times-\omega\times\rho_{G}\times$</sub>

So, in the end, the equations of motion are

$$ \begin{aligned} 
& \mbox{at G} & & \mbox{at B}  \\
{\bf f}_G & = {\rm J}_G \dot{{\bf v}}_G + {\bf v}_G \times {\rm J}_G {\bf v}_G
&
{\bf f}_B & = {\rm J}_B \dot{{\bf v}}_B + {\bf v}_B \times {\rm J}_B {\bf v}_B
\\
{\bf f}_G & = \pmatrix{f \\ \tau_G} & {\bf f}_B & = \pmatrix{f \\ \tau_B} \\
{\bf v}_G & = \pmatrix{v_G \\ \omega} & {\bf v}_B & = \pmatrix{v_B \\ \omega} \\
\dot{{\bf v}}_G & = \pmatrix{\dot{v}_G \\ \dot{\omega}} & \dot{{\bf v}}_B & = \pmatrix{\dot{v}_B \\ \dot{\omega}} \\
{\rm J}_G & = \begin{bmatrix}m\\  & J_{G}\end{bmatrix} & {\rm J}_B & = \begin{bmatrix}m & -m \rho_G \times\\m \rho_G \times  & J_{G}-m \rho_G \times \rho_G \times\end{bmatrix} \\
{\bf v}_G \times & = \begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\v_{G}\times & \omega\times\end{bmatrix} &{\bf v}_B \times & = \begin{bmatrix}\omega\times\\v_{B}\times & \omega\times\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

NOTE:

It is worth in to use material accelerations to derive the equation of motion [like with my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80449/392) and then transform back to spatial accelerations (with $a_B = \dot{v}_B + \omega \times v_B$) to simplify the terms.

Also, The term $J_{B}=J_{G}-m \rho_G \times \rho_G \times$ is the vector form of the parallel axis theorem. All throughout I am using $\times$ as the 3×3 cross product operator $$r \times = \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} \times = \left[ \matrix{0&-z&y\\z&0&-x\\-y&x&0} \right]$$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough answer! The reference I'm reading does not change the inertia tensor, i.e., the $\rho_G\times \rho_g \times \dot{\omega}$ term does not appear. Is this incorrect? If I am not mistaken, your $J_B$ is not necessarily symmetric?

Comment: Sorry, I was misinterpreting  the equation for $J_B$. I see it now. Apparently there is an error in the reference I was using. Sorry for my confusion and thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. It was lucky for you to catch me online. This is a subject very dear to my heart. 

Note that all 3×3 $J$ tensors _are_ symmetric as well as all 6×6 ${\rm J}$ spatial inertia matrices.