# How a stick in space moves when force only acts on one end? (suppose stick is rigid body)

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

I am confused with how to put inertia in to this problem, which suggests the end the force acts on should move first while another end remains fixed at first moment.

I think that the stick should sway forward and backward with central of mass moves related speed. But I have no idea how to describe swing motion in qualitative way.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is duplicated with: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72946/force-acting-on-a-simple-rigid-body-in-space

Comment: Related/Duplicate and links therein. [Will there be translation + rotational motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295731/will-there-be-translation-rotational-motion/295742#295742)